# order Arabic names in alphabetical order Mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to sort result in **alphabetical order** in Arabic but for some reason **not sorting correctly** ..

> $d1 = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT * FROM  `article`  where `type`='1' ORDER BY `name` ASC");
>    while($a1 = mysqli_fetch_array($d1)){
>               echo"$a1[name] 
> ";
>   }

this should show result A-z sorted or in arabic:

```
    احمد
    اياد
    بسام
    تامر
    جعفر
    حسين
    خضر
    ياسمين
```

but showing result ilke :

```
    تامر        
    جعفر
    حسين
    ياسمين
    احمد
    اياد
    بسام
    خضر
```

note : i am using utf-8 encoding ,
**utf8_general_ci**

**Full Mysql Code ::**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;


INSERT INTO `article` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `content`) VALUES
(1, '222', '', 'tst'),
(2, '111', '', '121'),
(3, 'جعفر', '', 'cont..'),
(4, 'احمد', '', 'cont..'),
(5, 'تامر', '', 'cont..'),
(6, 'اياد', '', 'cont..'),
(7, 'يحيى', '', 'cont..'),
(8, 'بسام', '', 'cont..'),
(9, 'بشير', '', 'cont..');
```

**PHP Code :**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';
$dbname = 'article_test';

 $connector = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) or die("Problem occured while connecting to Mysql Server..");
$d1 = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT * FROM  `article`  where `type`='1' ORDER BY `name` ASC");
 while($a1 = mysqli_fetch_array($d1)){     
            echo"$a1[name] <br />";
}
```

result should be :

```
111
222
احمد
اياد
بسام
بشير
تامر
جعفر
يحيى
```

does any one have a clue ?

Comment: [**Fiddle shows expected results**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1b3f/3) check your charset and collations for both db and tables

Comment: set your table and fields Collation to `UTF-8-general`

Comment: encoding is : utf8_general_ci , as i said in my question.

Comment: What do you get if you run that query in MySQL?

Comment: same issue , and i tried MySQL console , but arabic show in this form :┘â╪┤╪د┘ ╪د┘┘à┘ç╪»┘è| | |┘ê┘â╪د┘╪د╪ز| | |┘ê╪╣╪»| | |┘┘è┘ê┘è┘ ..unreadable..

Comment: @Hussein Are you using MySQL Workbench or just a terminal prompt?

Comment: i used the shell directly , no 3rd part app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the collation in MySQL to the appropriate value (I'm guessing `cp1256_general_ci`) for sorting alphabetically in Arabic to work.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,209072,209072

Comment: it is :utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Hussein Try [cp1256_general_ci](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-se-me-sets.html)

Comment: using cp1256 is not an option .. i want to use utf8 , i have a lot of ajax encoded witch doesnt work properly on cp1256 ..

Answer (score 0):

Try making this query beforehand:

```
mysqli_query($connector, "SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_set_charset($connector, "utf8");
```

If that doesn't work, run your query straight in the MySQL console and see what you get.

Comment: same issue , and i tried  MySQL console , but arabic show in this form :┘â╪┤╪د┘ ╪د┘┘à┘ç╪»┘è| | |┘ê┘â╪د┘╪د╪ز| | |┘ê╪╣╪»| | |┘┘è┘ê┘è┘ ..unreadable..

Comment: Can you give us a dump of the table structure + sample data you are using.

Comment: @Hussein Not seeing it.

Comment: What is the display page encoding? Also what code are you using? Also if you can post your updated code that would be nice, the above code you have has invalid syntax.

Comment: fixed the error , page encoding is utf-8 , all php code involved is shown above ,

Comment: @Hussein Nice. You should post the fix as a new answer and accepted. This way someone coming down with the same issue knows what the fix was.

Comment: @Hussein The error still exists in your PHP code. Can you please a more of your PHP code, preferably all of it.

Comment: Is this hosted somewhere or local? If hosted, please provide URL for that page. Everything seems fine to me, so it must be something you are doing that you are not noticing that is causing this. Try hosting the code and see if it works any differently form local (if you are using localhost).

Comment: @Hussein Email me your hosting info and I will check it out, nothing else I can do.

Answer (score 0):

While working with arabic language websites, you have to take care of three things:

1) Database Encoding  should be utf-8
2) Table Encoding should be UTF-8 
3) Check that all those fields which will be saving text data has also utf-8 charset.

if in you mysql consol, you dont see proper arabic charactors, it is because the console has no support for utf-8, or utf-8 is not enabled.

Check it in the browser, but the page charset should be utf-8, else you will see strange characters.

Thank you

Comment: i know that and everything is utf-8 and shows fine , but issue is the sorting .. it doesnt sort result correctly ..